# How to print specific values from dict_items?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict_items called `results` which contains the following:

```
dict_items([('rouge-1', {'r': 1.0, 'p': 1.0, 'f': 0.999999995}), ('rouge-2', {'r': 1.0, 'p': 1.0, 'f': 0.999999995}), ('rouge-l', {'r': 1.0, 'p': 1.0, 'f': 0.999999995})])
```

What I want to do is to extract the values of `f` from all items `rouge-1`, `rouge-2` and `rouge-l`

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, `for k,v in my_dict.items():...?`

Comment: It's a little weird to have a `dict_items` and not a `dict`.  You would typically only encounter `dict_items` when looping through a dictionary, not on it's own. Why are you dealing with a  dict_items object? Why aren't you dealing directly with the dict?

Comment: I tried several instructions and the errors was the same as I commented to the answer of @Tim

Comment: @Mark Actually, those results I obtained them from function `get_scores` from the library `Rouge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
results = get_scores()  # <-- the results contains your dict_item(...)

for k, v in results:
    print(k, v["f"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in ('rouge-1','rouge-2','rouge-l'):
    print( dict_items[name]['f'] )
```

If you want ALL of the items, there's an easier way;

```
for k,v in dict_items.items():
    print(k, v['f'])
```

Comment: Two errors have been occured. With the first code the error is `'dict_items' object is not subscriptable` and with the secod code the error is `'dict_items' object has no attribute 'items'`.

Comment: That means `dict_items` is not a dict.